# awk : trying to generate a query using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to write an awk program to generate a sql query, using the output from a pipe command. The output of the command will be something like this

```
Service name: APP1  
Service name: APP2  
Service name: APP3  
Service name: APP4  
Service name: APP5  
Service name: APP6  
Service name: APP7  
Service name: APP8  
Service name: APP9
```

and the result I need is something like :

```
select 'APP1' x from dual union all  
select 'APP2' from dual union all  
select 'APP3' from dual union all  
select 'APP4' from dual union all  
select 'APP5' from dual union all  
select 'APP6' from dual union all  
select 'APP7' from dual union all  
select 'APP8' from dual union all  
select 'APP9' from dual
```

I need to get the string after the "Service Name:" string, put it between quotes, and place it into the select. 
The first line must have the "x" after the string , and the last line must not contain the union all. There cannot be a space on the string. Since I don't have much experience with awk, so far I couldn't figure a way to do it.
I have this so far:

```
srvctl config service -db database | grep 'Service name' | awk 'BEGIN {FS = "[:]"}  
{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $2)  
    if ( NR == 1 )  
    {  
         printf "'select\ \''" $2 "'\'\ x\ from\ dual\ union\ all\ '\n"  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        printf "'select\ \''" $2 "'\'\ from\ dual\ union\ all\ '\n"  
    }  
}'
```

It will generate the following output:

```
select 'APP1' x from dual union all  
select 'APP2' from dual union all  
select 'APP3' from dual union all  
select 'APP4' from dual union all  
select 'APP5' from dual union all  
select 'APP6' from dual union all  
select 'APP7' from dual union all  
select 'APP8' from dual union all  
select 'APP9' from dual union all
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "select \047%s\047 x from dual union all\n", $NF; next}
      s{print s, "union all"}
      {s=sprintf("select \047%s\047 from dual", $NF)} END{print s}' file

select 'APP1' x from dual union all
select 'APP2' from dual union all
select 'APP3' from dual union all
select 'APP4' from dual union all
select 'APP5' from dual union all
select 'APP6' from dual union all
select 'APP7' from dual union all
select 'APP8' from dual union all
select 'APP9' from dual
```

Comment: Thanks man, just tested and , although it places the x alias every line, it's not a problem, this works just fine for me!

Comment: Glad it worked. I also fixed for removing `x` alias from 2nd row onwards.

Comment: awesome thanks! This was more of a "clean code" thing, both approaches are valid sql sintaxes, thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

perhaps simpler this way

```
$ awk -v q="'" '{print "select " q$3q (NR==1?" x":"") " from dual union all"}' file | 
  sed '$s/\w* \w*$//'

select 'APP1' x from dual union all
select 'APP2' from dual union all
select 'APP3' from dual union all
select 'APP4' from dual union all
select 'APP5' from dual union all
select 'APP6' from dual union all
select 'APP7' from dual union all
select 'APP8' from dual union all
select 'APP9' from dual
```

or

```
$ awk -v q="'" -v x=" x" '{print "select " q$3q x " from dual union all"; x=""}' file | 
  sed '$s/\w* \w*$//'
```

Comment: Interesting, this works as well, but do you mind explaining the sed part ? I see you used it to remove the last union all, but couldn't figure it out exactly how it works

Comment: sed removes the last two words in the last line. This simplifies awk to generate uniform output. first $ is the last line pointer, \w* corresponds to a word and the final $ is the end of line indicator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=" x"} NR>1{print prev " union all"; x=""} {prev="select \047" $NF "\047" x " from dual"} END{print prev}' file
select 'APP1' x from dual union all
select 'APP2' from dual union all
select 'APP3' from dual union all
select 'APP4' from dual union all
select 'APP5' from dual union all
select 'APP6' from dual union all
select 'APP7' from dual union all
select 'APP8' from dual union all
select 'APP9' from dual
```